# parsing json objects on python 3.6

Tags: python, json

i need some help with parsing json objects on python 3.6 .. 
i dont have any idea how to parse this jsons

```
({"d":"{\"events\":{\"keys\":[\"time\",\"room\",\"groups\",\"teacher\",\"name\",\"comment\",\"class\"],\"values\":[[1513593000,[71],[1309],9713,\"MATH\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513599300,[71],[1309],15653,\"ENGLISH\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513673100,[71],[1309],15728,\"SPORT\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513679400,[74],[1309],15651,\"BIOLOGY\",\"\",\"normal\"]]}}"})
```

or

```
({"d":"{\"events\":{\"keys\":[\"time\",\"room\",\"groups\",\"teacher\",\"name\",\"comment\",\"class\"],\"values\":[[1513673100,[71],[1309],15728,\"MATH\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513679400,[74],[1309],15651,\"SPANISH\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513683100,[71],[1309],15728,\"ENGLISH\",\"\",\"normal\"],]}}"})
```

i need time , room , teacher and name in separate variables for all lessons
(next i will decode it)
p.s: i have small experience in programming . and small experience with json objects . it is my first question here ...

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid JSON string.

Comment: i  think that i must replace "(" and ")"

Comment: use pandas read_json function

Comment: im getting this jsons from url's

Comment: [link](http://services.tsi.lv/schedule/api/service.asmx/GetLocalizedEvents?from=1513548000&to=1513734400&teachers=&rooms=&groups=1308&lang=%27ru%27)

Comment: The vale of `d` seems to be JSON. You should try to separate it. How depend on what you are showing us: a string or a Python structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a tuple `()` with a single element that is a dictionary `{"d" : "..."}` that has a single element with key `d` and a value that should be a JSON string.

If I remove the parentheses around the dict and the comma after `\"normal\"]`, I can read the contents into a dictionary like this:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(s['d'])
{'events': {'values': [[1513673100, [71], [1309], 15728, 'MATH', '', 'normal'], [1513679400, [74], [1309], 15651, 'SPANISH', '', 'normal'], [1513683100, [71], [1309], 15728, 'ENGLISH', '', 'normal']], 'keys': ['time', 'room', 'groups', 'teacher', 'name', 'comment', 'class']}}
```

Now store the result in a variable (e.g. `res`) and use dict indexing to access individual values

```
>>> res['events']['keys'][0]
'time'

>>> res['events']['values'][0][0]
1513673100
```

Answer (score 0):

For both examples you can do something like this:

```
from ast import literal_eval as le

a = ({"d":"{\"events\":{\"keys\":[\"time\",\"room\",\"groups\",\"teacher\",\"name\",\"comment\",\"class\"],\"values\":[[1513593000,[71],[1309],9713,\"MATH\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513599300,[71],[1309],15653,\"ENGLISH\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513673100,[71],[1309],15728,\"SPORT\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513679400,[74],[1309],15651,\"BIOLOGY\",\"\",\"normal\"]]}}"})

b = ({"d":"{\"events\":{\"keys\":[\"time\",\"room\",\"groups\",\"teacher\",\"name\",\"comment\",\"class\"],\"values\":[[1513673100,[71],[1309],15728,\"MATH\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513679400,[74],[1309],15651,\"SPANISH\",\"\",\"normal\"],[1513683100,[71],[1309],15728,\"ENGLISH\",\"\",\"normal\"],]}}"})


result1 = {k: le(v) for k, v in a.items()}
print(result1)
result2 = {k: le(v) for k, v in b.items()}
print(result2)
```

Output:

```
{'d': {'events': {'keys': ['time', 'room', 'groups', 'teacher', 'name', 'comment', 'class'], 'values': [[1513593000, [71], [1309], 9713, 'MATH', '', 'normal'], [1513599300, [71], [1309], 15653, 'ENGLISH', '', 'normal'], [1513673100, [71], [1309], 15728, 'SPORT', '', 'normal'], [1513679400, [74], [1309], 15651, 'BIOLOGY', '', 'normal']]}}}

{'d': {'events': {'keys': ['time', 'room', 'groups', 'teacher', 'name', 'comment', 'class'], 'values': [[1513673100, [71], [1309], 15728, 'MATH', '', 'normal'], [1513679400, [74], [1309], 15651, 'SPANISH', '', 'normal'], [1513683100, [71], [1309], 15728, 'ENGLISH', '', 'normal']]}}}
```

Then you can access to whatever values you want from the result which is a valid Python dict.